# how to query the relation in spring boot?

Tags: spring, laravel, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get students for a teacher where the student's age is larger than 18.

I used to work with Laravel framework, where I was able to do this by:

`$AdultStudents = $teacher->students->where('age'>18);`

Is there a way to do this in Spring Boot without using the mysql query? I mean using a single method from JPA Repository. Let us say something like this:

`teacher.getStudents().whereAgeGreaterThan(18);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, supposing you have your JPA Spring Data Repo you can construct the query by naming method as per the [Spring Data query method rules](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) passing the value as a method parameter.

In your example inside the Studends DAO supposing the `Student` has an `age` attribute a method named:

```
findByAgeGreaterThan(Integer age)
```

Comment: thanks, so in order to retrieve that for a teacher, it should be like this : 
`findByTeacherAndAgeGreaterThan(Integer id,Integer age);`
there is no way to get use from the relation `teacher.getStudents()` ?

Comment: Assuming you have an entity defined for `Student`, and a JPA repository for that, then you can construct a method with signature `List<Student> findByTeacherIdAndAgeGreaterThan(Long id, Integer age)`. That specific getter doesn't help you here unless you want to do the filtering in your business logic.